# How do you get a mesh to deform when you have it go along a path using follow path constraint?

Tags: mesh, path

The mesh object is highly divided so there are enough vertexes for it to deform (its not an 8 vertex cube) and I don't know armatures or have time to learn it. So I need a solution to deform the mesh as it goes along the path specified in the follow path constraint. thanks JK

Comment: I think you're looking for a curve modifier rather than a follow path constraint?  Constraints will never deform things; "deform" type modifiers, obviously, deformation is  their whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Nathan suggests, this sounds like a *Curve* modifier, with the modified object animated along its axis of deformation, rather than a Follow Path constraint:

[image]

There are plenty of answers here on the mysteries of aligning it.